# How can I increase width of a box every time I click on it?

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can I increase `width` of a box every time I click on it?

This is what I have tried so far

```
box = document.querySelector(".box")

box.addEventListener('click',()=>{

  box.style.width=box.style.width+"50px"

 })
```

Comment: `box.style.width` will give you an empty string if the style isn't applied via the `style` property, you can use `offsetWidth` like so `box.style.width = box.offsetWidth+50+"px";`

Comment: add the html as well please

Comment: i applied style property, i don't understand why this is not working in that way,

Answer (score 1):

You can use  `offsetWidth`(with border size) or `cientWidth` property to get the current div width.

```js
box = document.querySelector(".box")

box.addEventListener('click', () => {
  box.style.width = (box.offsetWidth + 50) + 'px'
})
```

```css
.box {
  width: 20px;
  height: 10px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Refer : [Determining the dimensions of elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSS_Object_Model/Determining_the_dimensions_of_elements)